# Is life insurance linked to mortgage always a good idea?

Tags: life-insurance, european-union, home-insurance

My husband and I are 30 years old, have stable jobs, and earn roughly the same salary. We are buying our first house, with a 35% down payment. The monthly mortgage works out to ~15% of our combined in-hand monthly incomes (after paying taxes and pension funds). Based on our current rate of savings, we expect to pay it off in 12-15 years. We do not have kids yet, but plan to, in the near future.

We also have some disability coverage, good health insurance, and no other debt. We plan to get fire insurance on the house itself (not contents).

My question is, do we need additional disability and life insurance linked to our mortgage? What about insurance on damage to the contents of the house against theft/accidents? Is there any statistical data that can help us decide? Our current assumption is that each of our salaries is independently enough to make the monthly mortgage payments, and also replace most of the house contents, so we do not need additional insurance. Or, are the premiums worth it?

Comment: Do either of you have death in service benefits?

Comment: @Pepone what is that? So I guess, no.

Comment: if you die while working you get 3 or 4 x your salary typical for FTSE 100

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Welcome to Money.SE. Please take a look at the recent question, [Why buy insurance?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/54561/why-buy-insurance). Much of the discussion of risk applies to this question as well.

The numbers look like your mortgage is closer to 10% of gross income. Life insurance in your case is a personal decision. In my opinion, life insurance should be to help loved ones left behind not experience financial trauma. The single wager earner dies, and leaves a non-working spouse with 2 toddlers and a mortgage? Trauma. Your situation? Not so much.

You should start to plan your mortgage needs based on the kids you expect to have. When running the numbers after we got married, we had a house that we each couldn't afford alone, and were planning a child that would go to college. If I were you, I'd look at the worst case numbers, and price out term that will cover your planned children, but perhaps not buy the policies until the first one is born.

House contents is purely up to you. You should ask your insurer what contents insurance for fire/theft will cost. Some people are minimalists, and can replace their entire furniture collection with a single paycheck. Others love there $10K leather sofa. If, as you suggest, you can self-insure contents, and would lose too much sleep repurchasing the contents after the house is re-built, that's fine.

To answer the original question - Term insurance. I'd never buy a policy tied to a loan balance. To clarify - as time passes, the mortgage payment is less painful, its real value dropping with inflation and your salary increases. But the very fact that you are earning more, and more valuable to your spouse and children points toward needing more insurance, not less. An the house, while it's great to kill that mortgage, has higher property taxes, along with higher maintenance costs as things need a round of repair or renovation. The need for insurance is more of a step function, and the use of multiple term policies can be timed to give you the right coverage depending on the stage of your life.

Comment: +1 for independent term insurance. Policies bundled with mortgages (or anything) are usually expensive (per dollar/euro of coverage) and specialized to that one thing. Unless you're uninsurable any other way, it's best to get your own policy on your own terms.

Comment: Re: *"I'd never buy a policy tied to a loan balance."* I agree, but elaborating for others may be helpful and will earn my +1  :)

Comment: Good question, good answer, and good comments.  Well done!

Comment: I'm confused - what is meant by linked to a mortgage?

Comment: @Ross most mortgage lenders and mortgage brokers will cheerfully sell you life insurance to cover the loan they're also selling you.  This is quick, easy, convenient and almost never a good deal.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea - I hope the edit was a good clarification.

Comment: @Ross Here you can buy 3rd party insurance with the same term as your mortgage, whose premiums (and payouts) decrease over the years, proportional to the annuity payment you make on the mortgage

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer thanks for the clarification. It's a very good insight that you actually might need more insurance, not less even though the mortgage left to be paid off is smaller.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I don't understand how you come to the conclusion "The numbers look like your mortgage is closer to 10% of gross income"

Comment: @NotANumber - The line "The monthly mortgage works out to ~15% of our combined in-hand monthly incomes (after paying taxes and pension funds)."  I realize OP is not in my country, but it's typical to net less than 66% of gross once you take out all taxes and some retirement savings. 15% of 66 is 10% of 100.  It's more common to view the mortgage in terms of gross income, not net.

Comment: Joetaxpayer thanks, I am the Op, and you're right. The mortgage works out to be 9-10% of our combined gross salaries. that's 20% of a single salary. Is that a healthy/payable mortgage for a single person?

Comment: (Acknowledging first that other countries are likely smarter than US as far as these policy matters) In the US, a well qualified loan will allow up to 28% of income to go to the mortgage and property tax. So yes, a big yes, to you that you arranged your finances so that just one income is still not a burden. You are both off to a great start.

Answer (score 6):

I will give a slightly different twist to JoeTaxpayer's answer
but what I say might be applicable only in the US whereas this
question is tagged `european union`.

All the
house mortgages that my wife and I had (as a two-earner couple) had a
clause stating that the mortgage became immediately due if either of us
passed away. In this event, the surviving spouse *could* negotiate 
a *new* mortgage to pay off the one immediately due, but that was yet
another hassle that the survivor would have to take care of 
"immediately" amidst all
the other things that also needed to be taken care of even more
immediately. 
So, we both had *term* life insurance policies to cover the balance due.

A typical (guaranteed renewable without medical exam)
term-life insurance policy has fixed face value and premiums that increase in steps; every year, or every two years or every five
years or every ten years etc. for the duration of the policy
(15 or 20 or 30 years).  It is/(was?) also possible to get a term
life policy with *fixed* annual premium for 15 or 30 years but with
face value that decreases much as the balance due on a mortgage
decreases: very slowly in the initial years and with a
more rapid decline towards the end of the term.
**We**, not the mortgage company, were the beneficiaries on each other's
policies so that this was not like PMI in which the beneficiary is
the mortgage company. That is, we could use the money for other
purposes if the balance was small enough not to need the entire
sum received from the life insurance company.

Now, all this was 30 years ago when most mortgages in the US
were issued by entities called Savings and Loan Associations
(anyone remember them?) and maybe
modern mortgages have different clauses in them. But I *would*
recommend *reading* the mortgage carefully, and if an 
"immediately due on death of either mortgagee" clause is still there,
then serious consideration should be given to getting life insurance
on both spouses to cover the mortgage balance due. The "linking"
to the mortgage is not really necessary; one should have enough 
*total* life insurance so that the surviving *family* can manage on just the income
of the surviving spouse plus judicious spending of the
life insurance proceeds, 
as well as enough money to support
the (soon-to-come) children of the OP at least through adulthood (or college)
should *both* parents pass away.

Comment: +1 and by taking out the life cover independently of the mortgage you have many more options and could well get better rates.  You may be required to take out cover of some sort.

Comment: Life insurance to cover the mortgage is definitely a good idea. The other answer assumed OP was asking about life insurance sold to the borrower as part of the mortgage process, without health underwriting, etc. (If you're healthy, any insurance you get that doesn't check _your_ health is going to be more expensive because it's group underwriting). Not criticizing your answer - you did it right - you went and got your own policy on your own terms.